# Python vs Java(script) for stellar apps. Is it worth learning a new language?

Tags: javascript-sdk, java-sdk, python-sdk, new-developer

I am starting to get into programming apps for crypto, and I would like to start on the Stellar network. My programming background lies mainly in C and Python, and I am a reasonably competent self taught programmer in both languages.

From my research it seems that there is independent open source community support for Python, whereas natively the network supports JS and Java.  I'm hoping that someone who has experience in this area can give me some insight into  the pros and cons of sticking with the language I know, but which is not natively supported, versus learning a new language for the sake of native support and presumably better documentation.  Are the benefits of native support worth the extra time required to get up and running with a new  language?

My eventual goal is to code both desktop and mobile apps based on the Stellar network, with my immediate focus being on interacting with the Stellar DEX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stellar JavaScript SDK features one undeniable advantage – it gives an ability to create a Stellar app that will work directly in a browser. Browser-based apps are easier to promote (no need to install anything on your smartphone/laptop), easier to support (single implementation for all modern browsers), and you can safely forget about versions hell (users always work with the latest version).

I'd say that you should start with a platform selection. If your app receives no clear benefits from running in a browser (for example, a trading bot or some sort of payment API), then you are free to choose any SDK you like. Officially supported SDKs (JavaScript, Java, and GoLang) may have better documentation, but community-supported SDKs are also quite good.

Comment: Browser development is not something I had considered. Definitely something to bear in mind.